# Groovy with JAVA: Error while merging multiple large PDF file, causing out of memory

Tags: java, pdf, groovy

I am trying to merge multiple large PDF files (~10MB) together with bookmark. 
It works fine with small PDF files, but not work if there are some very large file that need to be merged.

Below is the code I wrote in Groovy`

```
public class MergePDFBookmarks
{
    public static void mergePDFFiles(Map jsonobj, String pathname, String
pdfoutfullpath)
    {
        def mergePdf = new PDFMergerUtility();

        jsonobj.each{k,v->
                if (v instanceof List){
                v.each{it ->
                mergePdf.addSource(pathname + "/" + it["TLF_ID"] + ".pdf")
                        }
                }
        }

        println "Merging to PDF File: " + pdfoutfullpath + ".pdf"
        mergePdf.setDestinationFileName(pdfoutfullpath)
        mergePdf.mergeDocuments()
    }
```

ERROR Message:
I got the error message saying that

```
org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.StaticMetaMethodSite.call(StaticMetaMethodSite.java:88)
     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:40)
     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:117)
     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
     at MergePDFBookmarks.main(Script1.groovy:112)
     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
     at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:88)
     ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
     at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:2219)
     at java.util.ArrayList.grow(ArrayList.java:242)
     at java.util.ArrayList.ensureExplicitCapacity(ArrayList.java:216)
     at java.util.ArrayList.ensureCapacityInternal(ArrayList.java:208)
     at java.util.ArrayList.add(ArrayList.java:440)
     at org.apache.pdfbox.cos.COSArray.add(COSArray.java:52)
     at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.BaseParser.parseCOSArray(BaseParser.java:1092)
     at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.BaseParser.parseDirObject(BaseParser.java:1275)
     at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.BaseParser.parseCOSDictionaryValue(BaseParser.java:249)
     at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.BaseParser.parseCOSDictionary(BaseParser.java:356)
     at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.BaseParser.parseDirObject(BaseParser.java:1264)
     at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.PDFObjectStreamParser.parse(PDFObjectStreamParser.java:106)
     at org.apache.pdfbox.cos.COSDocument.dereferenceObjectStreams(COSDocument.java:683)
     at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.PDFParser.parse(PDFParser.java:255)
     at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument.load(PDDocument.java:1227)
     at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument.load(PDDocument.java:1194)
     at org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFMergerUtility.mergeDocuments(PDFMergerUtility.java:238)
     at org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFMergerUtility.mergeDocuments(PDFMergerUtility.java:195)
     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
```

Comment: I don't see any out of memory exceptions.  Is there more to your stacktrace that you did not include here?

Comment: @Daniel, my apologize, please see the update.

Comment: This is coming from pdfbox.  What version are you using?  You may also try tuning your memory parameters for your application increase available memory.

Comment: I am now using pdfbox-1.8.10, I tried pdfbox-1.8.16, not work, could you please tell me how to increase the memory? thanks!!!

Comment: From googling, it looks like there are some known memory problems with older versions of pdfbox.  Regardless, take a look at the solution presented here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38188184/apache-pdfbox-getting-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-when-using-splitpddocument-d to get an idea how to improve the memory usage rather than just loading everything into memory.

Comment: @Daniel, thanks a lot!!!